# DropDown State not preserving in React

Tags: reactjs, state, dropdown

I have A react DropDown Component as shown below:
[image]

Everything works fine when I make selections as shown below:
[image]

**[Reproduction Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wozniak-6js06?file=/src/App.js)**

Now here comes the problem, my dropdown open close handler works but each time it closes and reopens the previous values, even though they're preserved in `console log` but they don't show up in UI.

```
DropDownControlHandler = (handleElem) =>
    {
        const newState = this.state;
        
        newState.isDropDownOpen = handleElem; 

        console.log(this.DropDownElements);
 
        this.setState({state: newState,DropDownElements: this.DropDownElements});
        //this.CheckBoxChangeHandler(-10,this.DropDownElements);
        

    }

    CheckBoxChangeHandler = (index) => {

        
        let newData = this.DropDownElements;
        if(!this.state.isMultiSelectOn)
        { 
            console.log("Executing if");
            newData = this.ClearAllElements;
            console.log(newData);
        }

        newData[index].isChecked = !(newData[index].isChecked);
        console.log("New Data:- ");
        console.log(newData);
        this.setState({DropDownElements: newData});
        

    }
```

Can someone help me here? Here is the [reproduction link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wozniak-6js06?file=/src/App.js).

End Goal: On Closing and opening dropdown, the data should preserve and when `isMultiSelectOn` false then only one selection should happen and not others.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-water-mstbl your problem is that you assign it to value instead of checked prop, for multiselect there are post to solve that so you google it a bit

Comment: Wow you just saved me! Thank you so much never expected it to be that silly. And ok cool, I will check thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is already preserved, it is not being reflected on the ui because you are not adding the true value in its checked property, See the code below I have added the checked property now it is clearly reflected in the ui.

const DropDownBoxComponents = this.DropDownElements.map(

```
  (element, index) => {

    return (

      <div className={classes.DropDownContainer} key={element.id}>

        <input

          type="checkbox"

          className={classes.CheckBox}

          onChange={() => {

            this.CheckBoxChangeHandler(index);

          }}

          value={element.isChecked}

          checked={element.isChecked} // this is what you need to add

        />

        <div className={classes.CheckBoxElement}>{element.value}</div>

      </div>

    );

  }

);
```

I can't find isMultiSelectOn option in the ui so I can't tell the solution to that part of the question, but that ui part will work now on opening and closing the dropdown

Comment: HI @Kumar, thank you very much for the answer, didn't expect it to be that silly. Also Can you open my code sandbox link if possible? I have added that in my question...

Comment: for your convinience I am adding it here as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wozniak-6js06?file=/src/TextDropDown.js:0-5720

Comment: Anyways thanks, I sorted it out.. thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I was not online I saw ur comment now, but I am happy that u sorted it